# Can the Antyeshti mantras be modified for dead persons of unknown background?

Tags: antyeshti

I assume that antyeshti as normally performed is for dead persons whose background is known.

Can it be done for orphaned corpses?

Comment: The king performs, if noone assumes responsibility.

Comment: Yes. Anatha Preta Samskara has been specifically mentioned and koti punya ordained for the doer.